# how to set mapping for _id in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating a new index 'collegedatabase' with type 'studenttable' and my id are like 123,1234,12345 etc;
When I am trying to get record with id 1234 always it returning the record of 123 only.
I have tried to set mapping for '_id' field as follows:

```
{
   "studenttable" : {
      "_id" : {
        "index" : "not_analyzed"

      }
   }
}
```

Still it is showing same result.
Can anyone please help me with this.
I am using like this(It is from node.js)

```
client.search({
        index: 'collegedatabase',
        type: 'studenttable',
        id: req.body.sid
    },function(err,resp){ 
     .............
});
```

Comment: Can you show us how you have been searching for the _id? Does doing a simple GET index/type/id query work?

Comment: I am using SEARCH. If I use GET it is working fine.